# multiple controllers in Areas and Main site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have multiple controllers one in Areas

```
/Areas/Demo/Admin/AdminController
```

and other in main site

```
/Controller/Admin/AdminController
```

Now getting error

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Admin'.
```

How to resolve the issue? Better if I can change something in Areas/Demo as I have to use same Areas on multiple sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define namespace in your route. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492682.aspx

For example my area "Admin" is mapped like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "MvcBase.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```